# Hiding database errors in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, debugging

I want to hide *mysql errors* in wordpress when on deployment, as on errors I don't want to expose any sensitive information and table names.

I get the error like this:

> **WordPress database error:** [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ORDER BY name ASC' at line 3

***WP_DEBUG*** is set to ***false*** in wp-config, I tried this as will:

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

But does not work, how can I hide these message errors?

**Note:** *Just to clarify I know how to solve my error that is not the issue, I just don't want when unexpected error happens, for the query to be exposed. I can manually debug and solve that error.*

Comment: Isn't it easier to, you know, fix those errors so they don't show up at all?

Comment: Pretty old issue but wanted to just bump it. I'm also wondering how can I hide the errors. It's not like I don't want to fix the issues - I don't want to expose my db info when some **unexpected** error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably one of your plugins or theme that is the cause of the error. Do not try to hide it, try to eliminate it as some function which you might not be noticing right now would not be working correctly.

Try these steps:

1. Switch to a default theme and see if the error disappears.
   If switching the theme does not help, it means theme is not the
   culprit.
2. Deactivate all your plugins and check if the error
   disappears.
3. Now re-activate your plugins one by one to see which
   plugin throws the error.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can fix it, its not the issue, I just don't want them being exposed when theres unexpected issue. When an issue is presented I will debug an find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was also with this problem; The best solution I found was to apply the ini_set function by setting the display_errors to 0 so that it does not appear:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Hope it helps!